# Using orderByChild("column"), equalTo("value"), not returning any data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm running the below query and it is not returning any results.  However, if I change child_added to `.on("value")`, it returns the correct results.  It seems anytime I use `.equalTo` with `orderByChild` and `equalTo` it doesn't return results.

```
orderByChild("column").equalTo("value").on("child_added")
```

### Update

The actual cause of the problem seems to be:

```
function handleResult(vError, aData) { 
  console.log("auth with token successfully"); 
}
ref.authWithCustomToken(Token, handleResult);
ref.authWithCustomToken(Token, handleResult);
ref.authWithCustomToken(Token, handleResult);
```

This only logs to the console once. *Ensure you use the same URL when using new Firebase.*

Comment: From your self-answer it seems like you've found the cause. Without seeing the minimal code that reproduces the problem, it'll be difficult to say anything though.

Comment: Hey Frank, you can the command ref.authWithCustomToken(Token, function (vError, aData) {

  console.log("auth with token successfully");

 }); 3 times and you will note that it will only log to the console once.  Ensure you use the same URL when using new Firebase.

Comment: So put exactly that sequence of code in your answer. I'll take a first stab, but there's a handy edit link right under your question too. We had a question about this once before (subsequent calls indeed cancel the previous ones), but I couldn't find it just now. Having the proper code in the question and answer helps others find your question (and hopefully solve their problem).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer, in sort as mentioned at https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/authwithcustomtoken.html and other auth senarious:

**All Firebase references to the same database share the same authentication status, so if you call new Firebase("https://.firebaseio.com/") twice and call any authentication method on one of them, they will both be authenticated.**

The problem with this is that if you execute authWithCustomToken more than once passing a callback, it will only execute the callback for the last call.  Therefore, if your code is expecting your callback function to be executed for all authWithCustomToken calls, then you will have a failure at this point.

My solution was to first call reg.getAuth() and based on the return value, I ran authWithCustomToken or simply executed my callback with a success value.

For the firebase team, I would recommend executing the callback passed to authWithCustomToken  even if the user has called it multiple times, otherwise, it requires more code, gets more complex and will trick many users.  Next, I would update your knowledgebase with more information so that users don't get caught with this issue.